# Practical MySQL tips and literature for more advanced use?

Tags: mysql

This is yet another MySQL literature question. I asked for some MySQL / DBA literature earlier that day, but most of the suggestions were beginners guides that were more or less like a commented documentation with examples. Of course I can still learn a lot from these books / tutorials, too - but it´s NOT what I ask for here.

Rather I´d like to collect some advice for practical use – questions like "How to handle periodical imports of multiple csv files into an existing database (with foreign key constraints etc.)" should be covered in the literature I am looking for.

I am not sure where to search because most stuff i found is the typical beginners guide.

Thx for any suggestions – maybe it be printed or online…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rather I´d like to collect some advice for practical use – questions like "How to handle periodical imports of multiple csv files into an existing database (with foreign key constraints etc.)" should be covered in the literature I am looking for.

I'd say ask stuff like this here (or refer to the various questions in the field that already exist) - this is what SO is there for, and IMO is better suited than a book.

The scenarios and platforms surrounding things like CSV imports, backups, frequent maintenance.... are often so varied that I can't see a book giving solid advice here, when it often takes the creativity of several people to come up with a good solution.

I'll be happy to be proven wrong though!

Comment: had to check out this for a while, i got some really creative and interactive help and learned a lot. I also ordered the cookbook to give it chance, but only because I do not have to choose: I still can use SO :)

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL cookbook is pretty helpful for stuff like this.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001452

I also have a few helpful hints on my own site regarding replication and obscure optimizations.

http://chr.ishenry.com/category/mysql/

Comment: +1 for the cookbook. the table of contents looks really promising: a huge chapter on import / export. i´d +1 too for the link but i can´t obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

For admin / performance: High Performance MySQL: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067